# Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=12 "Timed out trying to set AX messaging timeout

Tags: ios, travis-ci, swift3, xcode8-beta6

I get this error when building my iOS app on Travis CI. Can someone please help me with that?

Config: OSX 10.11.6, Xcode 8 beta 6, Swift 3.

Comment: Please provide additional information in the question(e.g. is this error occurs always or only with specific code, code sample which throws error etc.).

Comment: Build link or bust

Comment: The error always occurs.Build link: https://travis-ci.com/Sharks01/actuTalk-iOS/builds/30186329

Comment: Same goes for [CircleCI.com](https://circleci.com), so it's bigger than Travis.

Comment: I'm getting this error too when running UI tests with an Xcode Bot.

Answer (score 0):

We're having the same issue on Xcode 8.1 using command line builds (not Travis). I found both links below useful. A machine reboot and test retry seems to mostly workaround the issue.

- [This GitHub issue on Travis suggested adding a build retry](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6519)
- [This Fastlane GitHub issue suggests "turning it off and on again"](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/5964)